# Creating a View SQL With Not Exists

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to create a view in SQL that I will use on my queries.

I am using the following tables:

```
customer (name:string,credit:integer)

loan (no:string,type:string,minCredit:integer)

borrower (cname:string,lno:string,due:date)
```

where `borrower.cname` and `borrower.lno` are foreign keys referencing customer, respectively loan, whose keys are name , respectively no (number).  Attribute `loan.minCredit` indicates the minimum credit required of a
customer to qualify for that loan.

I am trying to create a view that shows customers and loans they haven't taken.

```
Create view LoansNotTaken AS
SELECT c.name, l.no
FROM customer c, loan l
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT c1.name,l1.no
FROM customer c1, loan l1, borrower b1
WHERE c1.name=b1.cname AND l1.no=b1.lno AND lno=l1.no AND c.name=c1.name)
```

My basic idea in the second select is get all the customer and loans they have taken pairs. Then I'm trying to use the not exists to give me all pairs excluding those.  However my result only gives me pairs as long as the customer didn't take out any loans whatsoever, and I need the one they didn't take out even if they did take out some. Can anyone please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong in my query.

Comment: Can you explain your question with example. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) should be better

Comment: Basically you aren't excluding the loan matching itself, you need to add 'l1.no <> l.no' to your not exists conditions.  Giving some sample data and expected results would help people to understand your problem.  You also need a clause to exclude those with no loans (e.g. an EXIST clause)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the loans they haven't taken, then do this in two steps.  First, create a list of all customers and all loans.  Then remove the ones that are "taken".

So:

```
select c.name, l.no
from customers c cross join
     loans l left join
     borrowers b
     on b.name = c.name and b.lno = l.no
where b.name is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I did wrong in my query. But yeah I wrote my own tables to test these and kept editing it to test for different things. If I have any more questions I'll make sure to post tables and results to make it easier to answer.

This worked which is essentially what I had, I added type to have more data.

```
Create view LoansNotTaken AS
SELECT c.name, l.no, l.type
FROM customer c, loan l
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT c1.name,l1.no
FROM customer c1, loan l1, borrower b1
WHERE b1.cname=c1.name AND lno=l1.no AND c.name = c1.name AND l.no=l1.no)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Find pairs of names of customers who share the same loan. Avoid listing a customer with himself (e.g. do not list (Joe,Joe)). Also avoid repeating pairs which are equal modulo swapping the components (e.g. only one of (John,Jane), (Jane,John) should be listed).
I need a relational algebra and relational tuple calculus solution to this question, thanks!
Additional restraint: Do not use grouping or aggregation
I need answer for this question with same above the query